# Why does this code error the first time I answer gets.chomp but work if I repeat my answer?

Tags: ruby

The code below prints `"ERROR.  Please enter a proper pronoun: male, female, it or they"` set in the while loop the first time `gets.chomp` prompts for an answer, but works if you repeat the answer the second time. What am I missing?

```
def essay_writer(title, person, date, thesis_statement)
  puts "Welcome! Is your person male, female, it or they?"
  noun = gets.chomp
  noun.downcase! 
  while noun != ("male" || "female" || "it" || "they")
    puts "ERROR.  Please enter a proper pronoun: male, female, it or they"
    noun = gets.chomp
    noun.downcase!
    break if noun == "male" || noun == "female" || noun == "it" || noun == "they"
  end
  if noun == "male"
    pronoun = "I've learned a lot about him."
  elsif noun == "female"
    pronoun = "I've learned a lot about her."
  elsif noun == "it"
    pronoun = "I've learned a lot about it."
  elsif noun == "they"
    pronoun = "I've learned a lot about them."
  else
    puts "Fatal Error"
  end 
  person_new = "#{person}" + "'s contribution was very important."
  return "#{title}\n\n" + "#{person} was important in #{date}. #{pronoun} #{thesis_statement} #{person_new}" 
end 

puts essay_writer("Reef is a Puppy", "Reef", 2009, "Reef is an abnormally smart dachshund, renowned for his speed, and has won many local races.") == "Reef is a Puppy\n\n" "Reef was important in 2009. I've learned a lot about him. Reef is an abnormally smart dachshund, renowned for his speed, and has won many local races. Reef's contribution was very important."
```

Comment: For future reference, you can get code syntax highlighting to work on StackOverflow by indenting your code with four spaces. (There's a button to do that for a whole selection of code in the editing tools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is broken: `while noun != ("male" || "female" || "it" || "they")`.

That's not how you test a value against multiple other values in Ruby, or any language. It's syntactically valid, but it isn't doing what you think it's doing. What you have now will always evaluate `("male" || "female" || "it" || "they")` first, resulting in the value `"male"`, meaning your current loop is identical to this:

```
while noun != "male"
```

Meanwhile, you've written it correctly *inside* the loop, `break if noun == "male" || noun == "female" || noun == "it" || noun == "they"`.

You need either of the following:

```
while noun != "male" && noun != "female" && noun != "it" && noun != "they"
```

Or:

```
while !%w(male female it they).include?(noun)
```